# Ax7 - Custom lookup in form datasource field

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax7

I'm trying to create a simple lookup in a field of a datasource in a form.

The tables and related forms are BankAccountTable.

1.- Added new field BullCust (extends EDT CustAccount) and field group to new extension BankAccountTable.MyExtension.

2.- Created new form extension BankAccountTable.MyExtension and added new group to form.

This works OK. But now I want a simpler lookup. In Ax2012, I would override BankAccountTable\Datasources\BankAccountTable\BullCust\Lookup method, with something like this:

```
public void lookup(FormControl _formControl, str _filterStr)
{
    Query                   query = new Query();
    QueryBuildDataSource    queryBuildDataSource;
    SysTableLookup          sysTableLookup;

    sysTableLookup = SysTableLookup::newParameters(tableNum(ExcEC_DocuTypeTable), _formControl);
    queryBuildDataSource = query.addDataSource(tableNum(CustTable));

    sysTableLookup.addLookupField(fieldNum(CustTable, AccountNum));
    sysTableLookup.addLookupField(fieldNum(CustTable, Party));
    sysTableLookup.addLookupField(fieldNum(CustTable, RecId));

    sysTableLookup.parmQuery(query);
    sysTableLookup.performFormLookup();
}
```

In Ax7 this doesn't work anymore. Tried this approach (based on https://ievgensaxblog.wordpress.com/2016/05/01/ax-7-how-to-override-form-data-source-field-methods-without-overlaying/):

3.- Created class that manages lookup:

```
public class BullFormBankAccountTable_Handler
{
public static BullFormBankAccountTable_Handler construct()
{
    return new BullFormBankAccountTable_Handler();
}

public void BankAccountTable_BullCust_OnLookup(FormDataObject _formDataObject, FormControl _formControl, str _filterStr)
{

    Query                   query = new Query();
    QueryBuildDataSource    queryBuildDataSource;
    SysTableLookup          sysTableLookup;

    sysTableLookup = SysTableLookup::newParameters(tableNum(BullDocuTypeTable), _formControl);
    queryBuildDataSource = query.addDataSource(tableNum(CustTable));

    sysTableLookup.addLookupField(fieldNum(CustTable, AccountNum));
    sysTableLookup.addLookupField(fieldNum(CustTable, Party));
    sysTableLookup.addLookupField(fieldNum(CustTable, RecId));

    sysTableLookup.parmQuery(query);
    sysTableLookup.performFormLookup();
}
}
```

4.- Created class extension that subscribes and links apropiated events:

```
[ExtensionOf(formStr(BankAccountTable))]
final public class BullFormBankAccountTable_Extension
{
[FormDataSourceEventHandler(formDataSourceStr(BankAccountTable, BankAccountTable), FormDataSourceEventType::Initialized)]
public static void BankAccountTable_OnInitialized(FormDataSource _sender, FormDataSourceEventArgs _e)
{
    var overrider = BullFormBankAccountTable_Handler::construct();

    _sender.object(fieldNum(BankAccountTable, BullCust)).registerOverrideMethod(methodStr(FormDataObject, lookup),
        methodStr(BullFormBankAccountTable_Handler, BankAccountTable_BullCust_OnLookup), overrider);
}

}
```

And no result. I've debugged and BullFormBankAccountTable_Extension.BankAccountTable_OnInitialized() is properly called. But resulting lookup is the standard one, not the mine one.
Any ideas or example about how should this be performed?

(PS: version Ax7 Platform Update 9)

Comment: That probably doesn't answer your question but you may find it easier to override form control's lookup if you have difficulty overriding datasource field's lookup.

Answer (score 1):

I would not use a class extension to solve this, but rather an event handler on the control's OnLookup event. Just subscribe to the event and handle it in some event handler class.

Here is a potential code sample for you. I assume here that the datasource field "BullCust" is also a control on the form, as this overrides the form control and not the datasource field

```
public class YourEventHandlers
{
    [FormControlEventHandler(formControlStr(BankAccountTable, BullCust), FormControlEventType::Lookup)]
    public static void PWSCertificateProvince_OnLookup(FormControl sender, FormControlEventArgs e)
    {
        Query                   query = new Query();
        QueryBuildDataSource    queryBuildDataSource;
        SysTableLookup          sysTableLookup;


        sysTableLookup = SysTableLookup::newParameters(tableNum(BullDocuTypeTable), sender);
        queryBuildDataSource = query.addDataSource(tableNum(CustTable));

        sysTableLookup.addLookupField(fieldNum(CustTable, AccountNum));
        sysTableLookup.addLookupField(fieldNum(CustTable, Party));
        sysTableLookup.addLookupField(fieldNum(CustTable, RecId));

        sysTableLookup.parmQuery(query);
        sysTableLookup.performFormLookup();
    }
}
```

**Note**: you may need to cancel the super call depending on your use case if there is a framework lookup form being shown/generated.

Use:

```
  FormControlCancelableSuperEventArgs ce = e as FormControlCancelableSuperEventArgs;
  ce.CancelSuperCall();
```

Comment: There is a bug with registerOverrideMethod reported on a few other message boards.  This answer is the workaround, and a key piece of the answer is the CancelSuperCall if the form has a lookup method on the data source.

Answer (score 0):

Try only with FormControl parameter:

```
public void BankAccountTable_BullCust_OnLookup(FormControl _formControl)
{
    //same code
}
```

I checked it and works.